# SPARQL wikidata group-by: rivers with multiple cities

Tags: sparql, aggregation, wikidata

I want to ask wikidata which rivers have multiple big cities. The following query gives me a list where `?citycount` is an integer ranging from 1 to 13.

```sql
# rivers and cities
SELECT ?river ?riverLabel (COUNT(?city) AS ?citycount)
WHERE {
  ?river wdt:P31 wd:Q4022. # ... is a river
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q1549591. # ... is a big city
  ?city wdt:P206 ?river.  # ... located in or next to body of water
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]".}
}
GROUP BY ?river ?riverLabel
ORDER BY DESC(?citycount)
LIMIT 100
```

How can I restrict the results to those rivers with `?citycount` bigger than, say, 3?

Comment: `HAVING(?citycount > 3)` - see the specs https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#having

Comment: I already tried this, but put that clause at the very end after `ORDER BY ...` which gave me a `Query is malformed`-Error. Now it works. Thanks!
I guess you deliberately chose a comment instead of an regular answer? For copy-past-ability I answered the question by myself, but I of course can delete this in favor of an regular answer from you.

Answer (score 2):

Turning the comment of @UninformedUser into an answer:

```sql
# rivers and cities
SELECT ?river ?riverLabel (COUNT(?city) AS ?citycount)
WHERE {
  ?river wdt:P31 wd:Q4022. # ... is a river
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q1549591. # ... is a big city
  ?city wdt:P206 ?river.  # ... located in or next to body of water
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]".}
}
GROUP BY ?river ?riverLabel
HAVING (?citycount > 3)    # ← important line
ORDER BY DESC(?citycount)
```

see: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#having